# Internal server error .htaccess, nothing wrong with code?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is wrong with this code?
it works on my other server but not my new one.
here it is

```
  Options -Indexes
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?(somesite\.mobi)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websites/
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /websites/%1/$1 [L]
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
  AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  </FilesMatch>
  ErrorDocument 404 /member_not_found.php
  ErrorDocument 403 /member_new_index.php
```

Comment: Check the server error_log or the log for your virtual host.  Maybe mod_rewrite is not enabled?

Comment: Its arvixe buisness plan, anyone knows if mod_rewrite is supported there?

Comment: If the domain is not propagated yet everywhere? can that cause it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the error_log - I see that they are using cPanel, so there should be an option to view the error_log from there (I guess this is a shared account). If you have vps/dedicated and root access, just check /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log, it will surely supply more details.